# Melt a big wide-form data (1982 columns) into a long form and then cast it back to wide form in R efficiently

Tags: sql, r, data.table, dplyr

I've a data set in the format shown below, `df`:

```
# the original data format
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
       var1.20130101 = 1:2,
       var1.20130102 = 6:7,
       var2.20130101 = c(NA,1),
       var2.20130102 = NA)
df

# id var1.20130101 var1.20130102 var2.20130101 var2.20130102
# 1             1             6            NA            NA
# 2             2             7             1            NA
```

And the final output I want is:

```
df.out <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                     date = c(20130101, 20130102),
                     var1 = c(1, 6, 2, 7),
                     var2 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA))
df.out
# id     date var1 var2
# 1 20130101    1   NA
# 1 20130102    6   NA
# 2 20130101    2    1
# 2 20130102    7   NA
```

Hope this explains the actual operation I want to perform.

---

In reality, I have to perform this task on 24 CSV files. There are about 1982 columns in each file (and several thousand rows).

1. `id` column,
2. A column name corresponding to the `id` column and
3. 22 variables combined with three month dates (=> 22 * 90 = 1980 columns).

Here is my workflow:

1. Read the data (with `read.table`, somehow the `fread()` cannot read the original file) and split each file into 3 subfiles with each about 450MB.
2. For each sub file, read with `fread()` and `melt()` them.
3. Then extract the date and name information from the column names.
4. `dcast()` by `id ~ date + name`.
5. write the file back as a CSV file.

And here is the script I am using. I am looking for a more more efficient and automated (without splitting the file) solution.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/chencheng/rawdata")
  source("code1.2.R")
  file.name <- list.files()
  n <- length(file.name)
  for (i in 1:n){
    fileDispart(file.name[i])
    gc(TRUE)
  }
  setwd("E:/chencheng/step2file")
  file.name2 <- list.files()
  n <- length(file.name2)
  for (i in 1:n){
    dataTran(file.name2[i])
    gc(TRUE)
  }
```

code1.2.R:

```
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

fileDispart <- function(file){
  dat <- read.csv(file)
  n <- dim(dat)[1]
  unit <- 120000
  m <- ceiling(n / unit)
  start <- 1
  file <- gsub('.csv', '', file)
  ####################################
  for(i in 1:m) {
    if(i < m) {
      end <- i * unit
      start <- end + 1
      write.csv(dat[start:end, ], paste0(file, i, '.csv'), 
                  quote = F, row.names = F, na = "")
    } else {
      write.csv(dat[start:n, ], paste0("E:/chencheng/step2file/", 
         file, "_", i, '.csv'), quote = F, row.names = F, na = "")
    }
  }
}


dataTran <- function(pathin = "") {
  pathout = "E:/chencheng/"
  # dat <- fread("e:/chencheng/step2file/2013Q1p2_3.csv")
  if(length(pathin) == 0 | length(pathout) == 0) stop("Wrong parameters!")
  dat <- fread(pathin)
  n <- dim(dat)[2]
  dat <- dat %>% select(-2) # remove the extra column, 
                            # just chinese names of the id
  dat.m <- melt(dat, id = 1)
  rm(dat)
  gc()
  name <- as.character(dat.m$variable)
  name.len <-  nchar(name)
  dat.m$name <- str_sub(name, 1, name.len - 8)
  dat.m$date <- str_sub(name, name.len - 7, name.len)
  names(dat.m)[1] <- 'id'
  dat.m <- dat.m %>% select(-2) 
  dat.m <- dcast.data.table(dat.m, id + date ~ name, identity)
  # write the file
  filename <- gsub('.csv', '', pathin)
  write.csv(dat.m, paste0(pathout, filename, '.csv'), 
            quote = F, row.names = F, na = "")
}
```

Also, the server I am using is with 64G RAM (windows server 2008). R and SQL server are the only two options for me to do this task; maybe a little python is fine.

Comment: @Arun sry,... the data is actually confidential. Plus I just wonder if there was a better solution out there. Still, thank you!

Comment: @Arun, hope it;s clear now. And when I fread the whole data, I got the error: **Error in fread("I:/Dropbox/2013Q1p2.csv") : 
  Expected sep (',') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 929 on line 7 when detecting types:**. dunno why

Comment: Awesome! thanks. I see now. Will answer. And [try installing 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and using `fread()`, there were some bugs fixed by Matt recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite difficult to address such question without the sample of data, but some obvious optimization should be possible.
Not sure if it speedup much but you can try to not store intermediate data and use data.table chaining

```r
dataTran <- function(pathin = ""){
    # ...
    dat.m <- fread(pathin)[,-2L,with=FALSE
                           ][,melt(.SD, id=1:2, measure=3)]
    # ...
    # likely the following are redundant: rm(dat); gc()
    # ...
    # as.character, nchar, str_sub - likely those can be also speedup
    # ...
    filename <- gsub('.csv', '', pathin)
    dat.m[,-2L,with=FALSE
          ][,dcast.data.table(.SD, id + date ~ name, identity)
            ][,write.csv(.SD, paste0(pathout, filename, '.csv'), quote = F, row.names = F, na = "")]
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `melt(fread(.), id=, measure=)`? the `[, -2, with=FALSE]` would make a copy of the data. And so would `.SD`.. (until `shallow()` is exported).

Comment: Thanks! @Jan, but the answer here doesn't improve too much. Actually it works fine on the fread part. The neck is @ the rename part. I'm trying to convince my boss to get a copy online. It's just quite weird that nobody had this type of question before.

Comment: @BruceIce Don't know much about string manipulation performance. Regarding sharing sensitive data you may be interested in [Data Anonymization in R](http://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2014-11-07/Data-Anonymization-in-R.html)